# Dropdown list is been reloaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had created a dynamic dropdown list and got some data into it. this is been done in ascx.cs page and

When we select the Dropdown list  in asp.net,c#. I have been reloading the page and skipping the values. For example: I have a dropdown that have the values: 
dropdown - Id's (-- Select --,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

When Id is selected the Index Changed event would be fired and the dropdown value I would be sending into it. Then I want to capture that value in an session.

But when I select an Id then the -- Select -- value is been loaded into the dropdown to appear.

The actual think is when I select the value 3 or 6 or anyother based on the selection the data need to be appeared.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you binding dropdown list in Page_Load event ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind a `DropDownList` only the first time a user requests the page.
Check that the user is not posting back before binding on Page `Load`

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    //Bind your list here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding drop down list in Page Load event than put that code in  not IsPostBack condition

```
Page.IsPostBack Is used to check if the user posted back to the page. Meaning they 
clicked a button or changed a field in the form that causes it to post back to itself.
```

So , Code is

```
Page_Load Event
{
      If(!IsPostBack)
      {
            //bind dropdownlist
      }
}
```